# ¿Cómo buscar un dato en toda una tabla MySQL?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Estoy intentando buscar un dato en toda una tabla pero el resultado que me devuelve es toda la tabla.

Estoy usando como consulta esto:

```
SELECT * FROM c100 
WHERE creado_por LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR fecha_y_hora_de_creacion LIKE 'SILVA'  
OR auditor_asignado LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR nombre_beneficiario LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR tipo_documento_beneficiario LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR numero_documento_beneficiario LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR radicado_interno LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR sucursal LIKE 'SILVA' OR estado LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR parentesco LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR direccion_contacto_beneficiario LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR ciudad_contacto_beneficiario LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR telefonos_contacto_beneficiario LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR radicado_ecat LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR naturaleza_evento LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR asesor LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR subasesor LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR tipo_de_ingreso LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR numero_caja_archivo LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR fecha_recepcion_documental LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR nombre_victima LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR tipo_documento_victima LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR documeno_victima LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR fecha_fallecimiento LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR municipio_del_accidente LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR ips_atencion_medica LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR numero_spoa LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR despacho_fiscal LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR telefono_despacho LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR causales_devolucion LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR reclamacion_digitalizada LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR soporte_radicadion LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR fecha_radicacion LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR fecha_notificacion_estado_auditoria LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR fecha_vencimiento_subsanar_glosa LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR numero_paquete_ecat LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR entidad_financiera LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR numero_cuenta LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR fecha_expedicion_certificacion LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR soporte_certificacion LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR fecha_vencimiento_certificacion LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR nombre_persona_firma_conjunta LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR reclamacion_reprogramacion LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR reprogramacion_realizada LIKE 'SILVA' 
OR fecha_reprogramacion LIKE 'SILVA'
```

el usuario pone un valor como criterio de búsqueda y este se pasa por un post al php que realiza la búsqueda pero como pueden ver en este ejemplo se busca SILVA y aun así me arroja el 100% de la tabla.

Como puedo buscar en toda la tabla un valor X?

Comment: Si te devuelve toda la tabla es porque uno o más de los múltiples **OR** que tienes se está cumpliendo siempre en todos los registros de tu tabla.

Comment: reemplaza en tu query 'SILVA' por `'%SILVA%'`

Comment: Hay cosas que no quedan claras en tu pregunta y que creo que están llevando a confusiones. ¿Podrías darnos un ejemplo de dato que guardes en el campo **creado_por**? Actualmente solamente te devolvería ese OR los que tengan solamente 'SILVA' sin nada más. ¿Qué tipo de dato almacenas en **fecha_hora_creacion**? Si es un campo tipo fecha es absurdo buscar el string 'SILVA'. ¿Qué almacenas en tipo_documento_beneficiario? ¿Podría tener en algún momento el valor 'SILVA'?

Comment: ¿En en serio lo de tu consulta? ¿Por qué `Silva` podría estar en todas esas columnas? ¿Acaso no sacas provecho a la capacidad relacional de tu base de datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

deberías aplicarle el like '%SILVA%' a todos los campos
ya que algunos le aplicas like a una cadena vacía por lo que de todos modos se cumple la condición

```
nombre_beneficiario LIKE '%SILVA%' OR tipo_documento_beneficiario LIKE '%SILVA%' OR ...
```

Comment: aplicale de esta forma LIKE '%SILVA%'

Comment: Si señor con %ALGO% si realiza una búsqueda muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El problema viene por las clausulas `LIKE ''`, que son siempre match para cada una de las filas de la tabla. 
Eliminalas de la consulta si no deseas filtrar por esos campos.

Comment: Jose el problema es que se debe buscar en toda la tabla simultáneamente no por uno o dos campos.

Comment: Puedes buscar por todos los campos que necesites. Pero no debes incluir condiciones que impliquen siempre un resultado siempre verdadero, ya que no conseguirás filtrar nada y siempre obtendrás la tabla entera como resultado de la query.